# how to clear Window DNS cache

Tags: windows, dns, dynamic-dns

My router reset and my ip address changed. DynDNS was updated with the new address automatically. But windows still pings the old address.

How do I clear the DNS cache in Windows Vista?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do that with the command:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

edit:
You need to first write

> cmd

into the search box. That will open a command prompt.

Comment: Excellent!  Just what I needed :-)

Comment: My  pleasure! :-)

Comment: Worth noting that this needs to be done from an elevated command prompt if you have UAC enabled. If you simply put the command in the start menu box you would see a cmd window flash and quite possibly miss the error message and then wonder why it didn't work.

Comment: I editeed my Answer beacause of Graeme´s valid objection.